# JPA multiple transactions - commit not handled properly after a rollback

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following code (simplified for the sake of the question)

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
TypedQuery<T> query = em.createQuery...
for(T result : em.getResultlist()) {
   try {
      em.getTransaction().begin();

      // do some stuff, update the T object

      em.getTransaction().commit();
   } catch(Exception e) {
      // something has gone wrong, rollback the current transaction
      if(em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
          em.getTransaction().rollback();
      }
   }
}
em.close();
```

I am using JPA EclipseLink.

Basically, I want to update a set of tasks, take action and update their statuses. Sometimes the task action fails and I need to revert the change.

This works perfectly fine UNTIL something goes wrong with one of the transactions and the roll back is called. At that point any subsequent transaction commit IS NOT performed, ie the database is not updated.

I read "on rollback all objects managed are detached". I guess this is where the problem is... if correct how could I implement the desired behaviour?

Any help would be vastly appreciated!

Comment: You mean if you have 5 queries in between begin and commit and 3rd one fails, then you want that previous 2 updates to be reflected in database?

Comment: previous 2 are reflected, the problem is with the next 2. I updated my question as it was not very clear on what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I am misusing transactions. I thought they would be isolated but it appears the rollback "messes everything up" and all objects become detached.

Comment: It is the basic exception handling, which seems to be happening here, see if your 3rd query fails , then you will go to catch block , then it is not possible to go back to try block and resume from the 4th query.

Comment: No, the 4th and 5th one get processed as expected. It's just that the changes are not reflected in the DB.

Comment: is it possible for you to share set of transactions and your console logs of the sql statements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162872/discussion-between-garima-gupta-and-thomas).

Comment: OK, I solved it by returning only the ids of the objects I am interested in and between each begin/commit loading the entity I want to update. This way the entity I am modifying is not detached.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to reattach the detached entities using `em.merge()`, right after beginning the new transaction. It will not have any effect on entities that are already attached to the context. Remember to use the entity returned from the call to `em.merge()`, not the original instance. The only question is whether you trust the merged entity still reflects the most recent state; loading the entity by id within the transaction is a safer bet.